# Servicio windows creado con python - acceso denegado en la instalacion

Tags: python, windows, powershell

Estoy intentando instalar un servicio hecho en python, en windows 11. y aunque ejecuto el instalador como usuario administrador de power shell, me aparece acceso denegado (5) cada vez queintento instalarlo. La instruccion que estoy usando (con el ambiente virtual activo es:

```
(env) PS C:\cliente> python .\000_.py install
Iniciando Servicio
Installing service logsiaservice
copying host exe 'C:\cliente\env\Lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe' -> 'C:\cliente\env\pythonservice.exe'
copying helper dll 'C:\cliente\env\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32\pywintypes311.dll' -> 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\pywintypes311.dll'
Error installing service: Acceso denegado. (5)
```

Como dije anteriormente, ejecute power shell con privilegios de administrador, pero aun asi no me permite la instalacion.
Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque pueda estar pasando esto?
Saludos y gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0):

Instalar un servicio en windows requiere elevación del proceso que hace la instalación.

Intenta ejecutarlo de esta manera:

```
>Start-Process python -ArgumentList ".\000_.py install" -Verb RunAs
```

La documentación de [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3) dice:

> En Windows, puede ejecutar `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` para iniciar un proceso con permisos elevados. Esto eleva el contexto del usuario actual.

Otra alternativa sería iniciar una sesión elevada de PowerShell y ya dentro de esa sesión ejecutar tu comando actual, por ejemplo:

```
>Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Verb RunAs
```

El sistema confirma la elevación, inicia la nueva sesión de PS (en una nueva ventana) y ahora en esa sesión:

```
>python .\000_.py install
```